# Helm template .Files.Get function not workig properly inside a range

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to build a dynamic configmap manifest iterating through a values file list, using folder and file name. This is how my values.development.yaml looks like:

```
templates:
  folder: "foldername"
  files:
    - filename1
    - filename2
```

this is my original configmap, with the hardcoded file names :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: templates
binaryData:
  filename1: {{ .Files.Get "foldername/filename1.zip" | b64enc }}
  filename2: {{ .Files.Get "foldername/filename2.zip" | b64enc }}
```

this is how I've tried to start, but the .File.Get function donn't want to behave within the range, because I can use it normally outside.
When I use it like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: templates
binaryData:
{{- range $.Values.templates.files }}
  {{ . }}: {{ .Files.Get "foldername/filename1.zip" | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

get this error:

```
helm template template  -f deploy/template/values.development.yaml  deploy/template --debug         
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: 
Error: template: template/templates/configmap.yaml:14:20: executing "template/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Files.Get>: can't evaluate field Files in type interface {}
helm.go:81: [debug] template: template/templates/configmap.yaml:14:20: executing "template/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.Files.Get>: can't evaluate field Files in type interface {}
```

Needless to say that I don't know go language that much.
Can you guy give me some hints on how to build that list properly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the Go `text/template` language, `.` is a special variable that has several meanings.  Of note, inside a `range` loop, `.` becomes the current item in the loop, and so `.Files` refers to the `Files` field in the current loop item rather than the top-level Helm object.

You can get around this by saving either `.` or `.Files` into a local variable outside the loop:

```yaml
binaryData:
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- range $.Values.templates.files }}
  {{ . }}: {{ $files.Get "foldername/filename1.zip" | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

Now inside the loop `.` is the string `filename1`, `filename2`, ... from the `files` array; but you've saved the top-level `.Files` object into the `$files` local variable so you can refer to that.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your answer, that worked out, but moreover, how can I use foldername+filename as an argument for the $files.Get function? I know that within range context that value is holded on {{ $.Values.templates.folder }}/{{ . }}.zip, but is not letting me use it as an argument:  {{ . }}: {{ $files.Get {{ $.Values.templates.folder }}/{{ . }}.zip | b64enc }} throws an Error: parse error at (template/templates/configmap.yaml:15): unexpected "{" in operand and putting it in quotes like so {{ . }}: {{ $files.Get "{{ $.Values.templates.folder }}/{{ . }}.zip" | b64enc }} returns nothing