# How to pass multiple file names to helm template and read the content of the same into data field of a single configmap?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to pass data from files to configmaps in helm templates
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/

The requirement is to give the provision of adding multiple file names in value files.

The below code works fine in helm template when only one filename is passed. The file data is getting displayed correctly in data section of ConfigMap.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configmapFromFile.name }}
data:
  map.conf: |
  {{ printf "%s" .Values.configmapFromFile.fileNames | .Files.Get | indent 4 }}
```

Values file look like this :

```
configmapFromFile:
name: test-config
fileNames: config1.properties
```

how can we modify this to take data from multiple files(sample value file given)

Values file :

```
configmapFromFile:
name: test-config
fileNames:

- config1.properties
- config2.properties
```

Tried modifying code as given below, it is throwing error <.Files.Get>: can't evaluate field Files in type interface {}

```
{- range $fileName := .Values.configmapFromFile.fileNames }}
{{ $fileName }}: |-
{{ printf "%s" $fileName | .Files.Get | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Helm template .Files.Get function not workig properly inside a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864596/helm-template-files-get-function-not-workig-properly-inside-a-range)

Comment: The `range` loop rebinds `.`, so `.Files.Get` is trying to reference a field in the filename and not the top-level Helm object.  You need to save `.` or `.Files` into a variable outside the `range` loop.

Comment: Hello, The issue has gotten resolved with below snippet. Thank you.

{{- range $key, $filename := .fromFiles }}
{{ $key }}: |-
   {{- $.Files.Get $filename | nindent 4 }}
{{- end }}

 The object could be accessed with   “$ .“